# How to install metabase docker image on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-service, metabase, azure-container-registry

I tried installing docker image on azure but I get error running my application. I followed `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart` and executed below command to create a metabase docker image.

`az container create --resource-group xxx --name metabase --image metabase/metabase --dns-name-label yyy --ports 80`

This command was successful but my application won’t load when I tried to access my application through fqdn given by the above command. It returns connection timed out response.

Ps: posted this question on super user and yet posting it here too as I couldn't find `metabase` tag in super user.
 I am new to docker and azure so detail steps would be helpful

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine in my tests, when you specify the required port `3000` instead of port 80. See example:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name metabase metabase/metabase
```

Source: https://hub.docker.com/r/metabase/metabase

Comment: I am unable to execute the above command in azure  shell. Instead  I created a new container now on port 3000 by 
`az container create --resource-group xxx --name metabase --image metabase/metabase --dns-name-label yyy --ports  3000` Yet I'm unable to access the application. Could you please give me the command that u used in azure to create a docker image.

Comment: I think I got it... I am able to access it by going to the fqdn:3000/setup

Comment: Please accept the answer if this works for you. The docker run example I posted was from dockerhub, not the one to start the container instance in azure